# CSS not working with CakePHP, using MAMP

Tags: css, cakephp, mamp

i'm using MAMP on my MacBook Pro as a local server.  PHP and MySql are running fine.  However, i have a strange issue with CakePHP - CSS only works on homepage of my site and only by the two following paths:
'localhost' and 'localhost/index.php'

Using 'localhost/index.php/' however returns just the bare unstyled markup as does all other pages in the site. How can a slash a the end break the CSS?

A few searches have suggested this could possibly be a mod rewrite issue in apache, but i'm out of my depth to be honest - i don't know how to test if changes i make turn mod rewrite on.

As CSS works only for 2 specific paths, could it perhaps be a problems with my routes? I only have 2 defined - '/' and '/index.php/' - and they are both the same.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
James

Comment: Please show the code you use to add the CSS to the layout. Chances are that you're using relative filepath instead of an absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely as tbwcf says that you're trying to load the CSS files using relative file paths, but you should always use [CakePHP's helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1437/css) to add resource files to the layout:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('style'); ?>
```

The above will output

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

The benefit is that if you install the app to some other directory the path changes automatically:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/other/directory/css/style.css" />
```

Do *not* use relative file paths like `../css`. It will break the layout again in all but the simplest cases.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your MAMP configuration (or Apache within MAMP has mod_rewrite disabled. It looks like you have to follow http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/advanced-functions/edit-configuration-files instructions, edit template for apache's httpd.conf, search for mod_rewrite and uncomment this line in config template.

Comment: This is unlikely the case here -- CakePHP doesn't use prettified URLs to serve CSS files.

Comment: CakePHP uses .htaccess to route things to app/webroot dir where dispatching process for code starts, and - all assets are usually stored. So, when assets are accessed using path like domain.com/img/whatever.jpg - it's either has to be handled through mod_rewrite, either will require full path (/app/webroot/img/whatever.jpg) specified.

This relates to css and js as well.

Answer (score 0):

The slash at the end of the markup is most likely breaking the file path to your stylesheet. For example if your css is referenced as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
```

then adding the slash to the page URL would mean you'd need to jump back a step to get to the same stylesheet as it would no longer be in the same folder as the page you're on.

So you could add

```
../ before the reference like <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css" />
```

Or possibly an easier solution in this case would be to reference your stylesheet absolutely like:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8888/project/css/stylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's replies.  It turned out to be due to relative paths.  I changed the CSS path to absolute which made no difference.  I then changed the jquery path to absolute as i am using the less css framework and semantic grid system.  This fixed my problem.